# Pytorch resource contention in cross validation loop

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, cross-validation

I am new to pytorch and am trying to train a model inside of a CV-Loop.
For some reason I don't understand it keeps on throwing the following error:

`RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 12796, 14968, 18532, 3432, 26096, 12980, 3712, 10588, 15712, 22028, 8976, 4852) exited unexpectedly`

It seems to trace back to the following line in my code:

```
for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
```

For refference, this is the entire CV loop with training loop:

```
def train_step(model, dataloader, loss_fn, opt, device):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        print(f'batch {batch}')
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
        y_pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
        train_loss += loss

        opt.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()
    return train_loss / len(dataloader)

def validation_step(model, dataloader, loss_fn, device):
    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0
    with torch.inference_mode():
        for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
            y_pred = model(X)
            val_loss += loss_fn(y_pred, y)
    return val_loss / len(dataloader)

def train(model, training_loader, validation_loader):
    loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        print(f'starting epoch {epoch}...')
        train_loss = train_step(model, training_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, DEVICE)
        val_loss = validation_step(model, validation_loader, loss_fn, DEVICE)
        print(f'Epoch {epoch}/{EPOCHS} - training loss: {train_loss}, validation loss: {val_loss}')

def cross_validation_loop(k):
    data_matrix = load_data('data/test.csv')
    kfold = KFold(k)

    for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(kfold.split(data_matrix)):
        print(f'------------ Fold {i} ------------')
        training_matrix = data_matrix[train_index]
        #testing_matrix = data_matrix[test_index]
        training_loader, validation_loader = create_tv_dataloaders(training_matrix, BATCH_SIZE)

        model = SpectrumNet()
        train(model, training_loader, validation_loader)

cross_validation_loop(k=K)
```

At first I assumed that this happened due to memmory overflow - but monitoring my RAM didn't support that hypothesis.
Also, from what I can tell, it's not an issue of CPU capacity, since the error percists when configuring the DataLoader object with merely one worker.

So I figured it probably has something to do with resource contention somewhere in these nested loops. But I really don't have a clue where this issue originates from.

Any ideas?